# Magento uploading images issue

Tags: image, magento

So im having an issue with uploading my pictures to Magento backend.
I can browse for the file. I can upload the file. the file is then sitting viewable to me as I roll my mouse over it. I then tick all 3 boxes so this can be seen on the front end. everything so far is fine.

After I click save I go back onto my products through the back end and I move my mouse over the picture once again, the picture vanishes and is not viewable on the front end, but I do still have the options of where this image can be seen. But it is not there?

I have tried a few things and nothing so far

Comment: What kind of thing did you? Please explain more.. then we can underhand of your problem.

Comment: usually once a product is saved and you go back onto the 'image' section of your product you have the image on your left then working your way right you have the label then sort order then store view selections then exclude and remove. well all of that is fine for me the only thing is that where there is usually a picture there is just writing saying 'no image' but when I uploaded the image i was able to run my mouse over it and see it so it was there just before I saved it.... also i tried a different picture and that picture works? they're the same rez and size and everything

Comment: **Steven**, Images are displaying in front end ??

Comment: They aren't showing on the front end after I save it or after I go back in to re check the picture in the image section

Comment: You uses any kind of module which  called `catalog_product_save_after` or `catalog_product_save_before` event??

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete .htaccess file in media folder.